# Changing default digest method in itsdangerous

Tags: python, cryptography, hashlib

Attempting to change the default digest method in itsdangerous.  Code snippet follows.  Question(s) - should I be getting the same signed result?  Am I setting the digest method properly?

```
from itsdangerous import Signer
import hashlib
s = Signer('secret-key')
s.default_digest_method = staticmethod(hashlib.sha1)
print ('sha1-->', s.sign(b'my string'))
s.default_digest_method = staticmethod(hashlib.sha256)
print ('sha2-->', s.sign(b'my string'))
```

Results are:

```
sha1--> b'my string.wh6tMHxLgJqB6oY1uT73iMlyrOA'
sha2--> b'my string.wh6tMHxLgJqB6oY1uT73iMlyrOA'
```

Comment: `default_digest_method` is used when *creating* the signer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default_digest_method` is used when the signer is created unless the `digest_method` is not passed. Use `digest_method` argument:

```
import hashlib
from itsdangerous import Signer

s = Signer('secret-key', digest_method=hashlib.sha1)
print('sha1-->', s.sign(b'my string'))
s = Signer('secret-key', digest_method=hashlib.sha256)
print('sha2-->', s.sign(b'my string'))
```

output:

```
sha1--> b'my string.wh6tMHxLgJqB6oY1uT73iMlyrOA'
sha2--> b'my string.PVHY4OzY_ekIpRd3A5G0vzTkhg8wSod5E3p90JgBCKw'
```

---

If you want to override the default digest method, you need to modify class attribute before you create the signer object:

```
Signer.default_digest_method = hashlib.sha1
s = Signer('secret-key')
print('sha1-->', s.sign(b'my string'))

Signer.default_digest_method = hashlib.sha256
s = Signer('secret-key')
print('sha2-->', s.sign(b'my string'))
```

Comment: I see that the OP made the original mistake, and that they expected `sha2`. Feel free to adapt.